# Azure automation not exporting to Git

Tags: azure, azure-automation

When I integrated Source control with GIT, my expectation was that the run-books I created in portal will be saved in git. Just like I did with Azure Data Factory. But after following [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/source-control-integration), I see it works the other way around. We need to have files in Git and the 'integration' is about importing to Automation account from GIT. The article does not say how to get the files in Git. Is it arm template?

How can I take my automation account to GIT(all runbooks and schedules) for tracking? Is there a way to automate it using Devops pipeline or so?

Comment: Not sure its clear on what you are trying to achieve. Can you please elaborate more on the scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

It is a one way integration unlike ADF.
In Azure automation only ACC and PRD need to be integrated with Git.
We first start in DEV and test it. Once it is over we can go to each automation runbook and export it as a file onto your local disk. Then upload these files to git(which is pointing to ACC and PRD). When a commit happens in git ACC and PRD will be published automatically(if that is what we set when we configure ACC/PRD git integration). Managing branches would be nightmare though with this 'never-heard-before' approach.

For ADF it is the other way around. DEV is integrated with GIT and is a two-way integration. Pull request to master and then we create a release branch to deploy to ACC And PRD. ACC And PRD is not integrated with GIT.